# Cakephp Account Activation Email - Address Not Found On Server

Tags: email, cakephp, activation, email-address

For our website, we set up the account activation email with the following tutorial (in cakephp):

http://www.jonnyreeves.co.uk/2008/06/cakephp-activating-user-account-via-email/

On our live site, it seems that the activation works for the most part, however some people are receiving the following error when clicking on the activation email link to activate their account:

Error: The requested address '/users/activate/36/10a1a794' was not found on this server.

This is odd to me because the link looks fine: "users" controller, "activate" action, user_id = 36, and hash code = 0a1a794.  Not sure why this error is happening.  One thing I read is to clear the files in the cache folder and that didn't seem to change anything.  Please help thanks!

Comment: Well, we won't know either without being able to look at your app or log files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activation hash has limited validity(same day).

So if send the activation email on 1st of any month, it will be valid till 11:59pm of 1st. The link wont work after 12:00am(technically 2nd of the month).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I actually removed the day thing and just use the email address by changing it to:

return substr(Security::hash(Configure::read('Security.salt') . $this->field('email')), 0, 8);

This should make it valid forever but still seems to trigger the same problem.  Does anyone know what the 0 and 8 flag do?

Comment: 0 - 8 is the length of the substring in your example that would be(10a1a794). Going forward to the problem in hand check the controller action the user is sent to when he clicks on the link. First check if the controller action has two parameters

Comment: .... function whatever(id=null, signature=null), if it does next check if the signature generated in this action is similar to the one that sent the email. Tip# copy the code that generates signature from both actions and use a single id(in this case 36) on both, and check if they generate same output. That's the whole idea. Hope that helps.

Comment: The function works.  In fact, for most users the activation works properly. But for some, cake is saying "The requested address was not found on this server." It doesn't seem to have anything to do with the function at all.

Comment: This is the best I can do without being able to look at your app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's what Josh R said, the hash is computed for the same day and this is a VERY bad idea.

You should either stop hashing the date or validate against two values: one for today's date, one for yesterday's date.

Also, a recommendation: don't just go there and copy the files, try to learn something from it and please, do it your way. You'll learn a lot more.